# How to overcome missing values in Highstock-Stockchart?

Tags: highcharts

Maybe I'm looking over it but I don't think this is a setting in the chart (otherwise my excuses in advance).

I have some values over 3 years about the workload of a printserver. For some days I have 24 values (one per hour), for other days I have no values (in the database, because the value is 0 and it would be overkill to create records with value 0).

The visible chart doesn't seem to take those missing values into account, although each value is identified by the Unix Timestamp and the chart could fill up the missing values as 0.

Is this possible with an option in the chart or do I have to rebuild my data and fill up the missing values myself?

You can see this clearly on this image (not enough points to upload images).
http://driezel.be/Values.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unforutnately highstock doesn't support parsing your data, but You can try to set tickInterval (http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickInterval) or prepare data with correct values, before highstock initialization.

Comment: The tickInterval did not work out. The values kept missing. I changed my function that builds the data and filled up the zero-values myself. I had been nice if it was possible but certainly not a problem.

Thanks!